# Missing character: There is no <umlaut> in font

Tags: xetex, fontspec

When I run this code:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode


\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Garamond}

\begin{document}
ö
\end{document}
```

I get this comment in the log: `Missing character: There is no ̈ in font Garamond/OT:mapping=tex-text;!` The character is properly displayed in the pdf. Is this a problem if the code compiles and displays everything properly? Why is this applying only to umlauts and not accents?

Comment: As far as I know, umlauts can consist of two symbols (if the font does not have it), e. g. `o + :` and they seem visually fine. To test this, try and copy the text from the pdf and insert it into a text file. In LaTeX I use the `fontenc` package with the `T1` option for that issue.

Comment: When I copy/paste from the pdf I get `ö`. Are there any downsides to this issue, such as loss of speed when compiling? Also, is there an easy way of finding out which fonts support the umlaut (besides testing it manually)?

Comment: the harfbuzz library in xetex is able to fallback from o + combining accent to ö. So if the output is okay you should be fine.

Comment: Also you should not get the warning in the next release of latex (before texlive 2017) as it should detect the missing composite and use the combining character, so it will also work in luatex.